# Adjusting the css scroll bar track to move it x px to right and y px down

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I have an HTML table which has `overflow: auto`. I get two scroll bars: horizontal and vertical.

I have made the first row and first column sticky, ie. they do not move with the scroll.

The problem is the scroll bar track is starting from the first row vertically and first column horizontally. I want the scroll bar track to be placed or to be started from the second column horizontally and second row vertically

I should get the scroll bar to be like this in the image shown here

Comment: You can't change where the scrollbar track sits within an element. To do what you need you would need to have separate elements for the 'frozen' content, and the other content which should scroll.

Comment: no but I have them as a table like this      <div class="table-container">
            
                <table id="matchup-table">
                    <thead>
                        
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        
                        <!-- Match scores will be added here dynamically -->
                    </tbody>
                </table>
    
               
        </div>